# How do I run MongoDB and SOLR Docker images that work with Windows Server 2016?

Tags: solr, mongodb, docker

I'm trying to configure my Sitecore 8.2 instance in a Docker container using Windows Server 2016. I've been able to successfully setup IIS in a Docker container, but am unable to find any containers/layers that contain Windows versions of MongoDB and SOLR, which means that I can't really run Sitecore inside of Docker.

**Question**

- Has anyone else been able to make this happen?
- Where do I get the Windows versions of those services for Docker?

Comment: Mongo has now released official images: [https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mentioned in comments that you're getting an error—this is because there is no tag in my docker hub repository. I wouldn't know which version of Sitecore latest should be build against: 8.2 or 8.1 update 3, and on the top of that, which version of SolR. So I choose to go with the tag 8.2.

So you would have to pull it with the following command:

```
docker pull istern/solr-sitecore:8.2
```

I will create a latest when I have the time so it is easier to pull, so a big sorry that this wasn't clear from the beginning.

Now in regards to running the entire Sitecore setup in a Docker container, you would have to switch to using a Windows container. Note that the Solr container I built is a Linux version.

So to answer the initial question, you would have to install the latest beta of Docker found here, choose "Beta":

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Make sure your Docker is using Windows containers, and you are running on windows 10 latest update.

And yes i have a version Sitecore 8.2 running in docker using Lucene, Windows, Mongo, Sql Express 2016.

You cant mix Linux and Windows containers yet.

Pbering did a post on setting up Docker and Sitecore. You can find it here:

http://invokecommand.net/posts/sitecore-and-docker-today

I'm also working on a post on this but this is still just a work in progress.
There is a windows mongo image created microsoft see it here
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/sample-mongodb/

Comment: So now you can use solr with windows just pushed a windows version of the solr image for sitecore 8.2 get use it  like docker run -d- p 8983:8983 -m 521 --name mysolr  istern/windows-solr54

Comment: Hi Thomas! Thank you for the updated image! I've been able to get the image downloaded now and it runs, but it immediately stops after it runs. What else do I need to do in order to get the docker image to remain in the "started" state? I don't think that I'm getting any errors (at least there aren't any being reported in the powershell command prompt).

Comment: Hi Keith Could you post the docker command you start the image with. You could try this docker run -d- p 8983:8983 -m 4g --name mysolr istern/windows-solr54

Comment: I've also added and Mongo image you can grab it here https://hub.docker.com/r/istern/windows-mongo/

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: Mongo has now released official images: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/!

As far as I know, no one has created public Windows based images solr yet...

That said, it should be pretty easy to do. Here are some examples of creating images for traefik/nginx that I created that can help you get started:

traefik.io on "nanoserver": https://github.com/pbering/Socker/blob/master/docker/traefik-win/Dockerfile and

nginx on "windowsservercore": https://github.com/pbering/SitecoreContainers/blob/master/images/winnginx/Dockerfile

Comment: Get a Windows version here https://hub.docker.com/r/istern/windows-mongo/

Comment: Official Solr containers here: https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/ they are Linux containers though and don't have many of the versions that are recommended for compatibility on the Sitecore KB: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

Can't wait until, hopefully someday, Sitecore is .NET Core based and can run in a Linux container.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a docker container for mongodb and Solr created by Thomas Stern over at his blog that describes how to use it and get started: https://blog.istern.dk/2016/10/04/solr-docker-container-for-sitecore-8-2/

In addition you can find the project here at github: 
https://github.com/istern/Sitecore-Containers/tree/master/containers/solr/sitecore8.2

And the container image is at dockerhub at: https://hub.docker.com/r/istern/solr-sitecore/

Comment: When I try to pull down that docker image using (docker pull istern/solr-sitecore), I get the following error: Using default tag: latest, Error response from daemon: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.
That image doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The image Thomas has created is Linux based so it will not work when you are connected to a Windows docker host.