# Unable to start Solr service on Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016 x64

Tags: solr, nssm

I'm trying to install Solr service as described [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1212/272). I use NSSM [prelease build 2.2.4-101](https://nssm.cc/download) to *'avoid an issue with services failing to start'*, but after installation the service cannot start anyway:

[image]

Windows logs say the following:

```
Started C:\solr\bin\solr.cmd start -f -p 8983 for service solr in C:\solr\bin.
Program C:\solr\bin\solr.cmd for service solr exited with return code 0.
Killing process tree of process 24764 for service solr with exit code 0
Killing PID 24764 in process tree of PID 24764 because service solr is stopping.
Service solr action for exit code 0 is Restart. Attempting to restart C:\solr\bin\solr.cmd.
Service solr ran for less than 1500 milliseconds. Restart will be delayed by 32000 milliseconds.
```

[Solr 5.4.1]

**Update:**
I managed to [install it on Win10](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/7841/272), but failed to install it on Win 2016 Server... All the tools and installation steps are the same. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: This is purely a Solr question and would best be asked on Stack Overflow

Comment: I had also faced the same issue and resolved it. the solution can be find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391729/solr-in-component-services-shows-paused-and-cant-start-on-windows/48700769#48700769

Comment: Another thing - if you have Java 10 installed, and solr is not working check this [blog](https://trayek.wordpress.com/2018/06/06/installing-solr/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It was because the port was already used by another solr service installed via [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/solr).

**Update:**
Tried to run `solr.cmd start` in `C:\solr\bin` foolder. Appeared that `JAVA_HOME` environment variable was missing. Adding the variable fixed the service.

Comment: Just to expand slightly on this answer, if you find you can start SOLR up via the command line, but the service fails to start as described in the question then you've probably but JAVA_HOME in your 'User Variables' rather than the 'System Variables'

Comment: I had also faced the same issue and resolved it. the solution can be find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391729/solr-in-component-services-shows-paused-and-cant-start-on-windows/48700769#48700769

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same problem. The solr starts when we execute `solr start -p 8983` on the command prompt of solr bin folder. But when we try to start the same from services, then it gives the above error.

**Solution:** Please check the environment variable path of `JAVA_HOME` on your system. It should point to the path, where the java has been installed on the system.

I corrected the path, and this solves my problem.

Hope this helps.