# Installation with different Solr port

Tags: solr, sia

I've set a different port for the installation of Solr 8.1.1

Using the SIA it seems to install ok but if I continue on with the installation I get:

[image]

If I go to Services I can see that it's not running.  I click start and it says it is running.  But then 20 or so seconds later it has stopped itself.

Looking at the log file there seems to be an error about a valid Keystore.

[image]

I currently have existing sites using a different version of Solr so I can't use the default port.  Is there a trick to installing Sitecore 9.3 with Solr on a different port number?  Was looking forward to the installation just working.

Edit - I have solr 7.2.1 running successfully currently.

Update:  I have tried installing Solr 8.1.1 myself following Chris Auer's answer on:

[How to get Solr to run as a service?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/how-to-get-solr-to-run-as-a-service)

It all seems successful - says that the service was installed successfully but then in services, it is in a Paused state.  If I click resume it just goes back to pause.

The only file in my logs folder is:
[image]

Which looks totally different from what I installed via the SIA.
[image]

Navigating to the URL just says connection refused.

[image]

Trying to run the command manually gives me this error:
[image]

I do have Solr installed to c:\program files\bitnami - so it kind of looks like it's not handling the space in program files?  But I'm not sure where this would be specified/fixed.

Comment: There is no dependency on Solr Port for Sitecore 9.3 installation, It seems like your Solr is not working properly, Please check for SSL certificate and Java version installation on your system.

Comment: The error logs say that , SOLR should be running on HTTPS Mode.

Comment: Solr 7.2.1 is running no issues.  Where should I be checking these things for 8.1.1  I just expected the SIA to set it up with no manual intervention.  Have I missed some pre-requirement check?

Comment: I have confirmed that I'm running the required version Java.  I have 1.8.0_202

Comment: Did you check windows event logs.? any error logged there. Sometimes that will give additional info about the issue.

Comment: Yeah struggled to find anything there. But when I tried starting the service manually I saw an error message. Anyway fixed now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out Solr was not happy about being located under c:\Program Files\Bitnami.  Changing to C:\Solr and the service installed.

However trying to install the solr service myself resulted in an invalid certificate error.  So I tried again to use SIA to install the solr service newly and that was all good.

Also noting if you have a failed attempt - you need to delete the sql databases, otherwise you get errors about users already existing, you also need to cleanup if it fails after installing a service (in my case I had picked an expired license initially which wasn't picked up in validation).

Also discovered when SIA fails you only have the option to Close - you can't go back to retain all the information you entered in to tweak and try again.

Got there in the end!  I'm sure this would have worked like a dream had I not had a space in the Solr Path initially - but it worked with Sitecore 9.1 and Solr 7.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post awhile back stating that if you want to run multiple instances on the same machine you need to have a JAVA (JRE) version that will work with all the SOLR versions. Then, what you need to do is modify the following file (may be different in 9.3):

```
App_Config\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config
```

Point to the port you want in the Sitecore instance you are installing. This will allow you to have multiple versions of SOLR on the same machine.

```
<!-- SERVICE BASE ADDRESS
    Base url of the Solr server. (minus any cores and minus a trailing slash)
-->
<setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" value="http://localhost:8985/solr" />
```

Here is a link to the full blog post: https://sitecoresandbox.com/2018/04/06/install-multiple-instances-of-solr-for-sitecore-development/

Comment: The JRE version I already have is compatible with Solr 8.1.1  - I seem to be having Solr Installation issues - so I can't even get to the point of installing 9.3 :(  But thanks.